# WCF Interoperability Kerberos SPNego Enabled Web Service

Tags: wcf, soap, active-directory, wcf-client, spnego

We have a test Windows Server 2012 Domain. There are two computers which are members of this Domain.

One computer is being developed by the Oracle Corporation and is running a version of Linux on a Virtual Machine. This machine is hosting a SPNego Kerberos authenticated Web Service presumably hosted by IBM WebSphere.

The other computer is a Windows XP Client hosted on a Microsoft Virtual Machine.

We created the SPN's inside of Active Directory to authenticate users using Kerberos.

We then tested the Web Service using a browser. The WSDL address brought back the SOAP data perfectly.

The Kerberos was turned off so Client Proxy code could be incorporated into a WCF 4.0 client and turned on again for testing authentication.

Why are all kinds of Security related errors being raised when trying to connect to the Web Service by using the methods provided in the Client Proxy?

> ```
> The remote HTTP server did not satisfy the mutual authentication requirement.
> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
> ```

The client-side App.config file used to connect to the Web Service:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://oag:8080/pos/GetStoreConfigurationService"
                  binding="wsFederationHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsFederationHttpBinding_ESLGetStoreConfigurationBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"
                  contract="ESLGetStoreConfigurationPortType"
                  name="wsFederationHttpBinding_ESLGetStoreConfigurationPort" >
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="http/oag:8080"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="UsernameBinding">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <security authenticationMode="Kerberos"  
                          requireSecurityContextCancellation ="false"
                          requireSignatureConfirmation="false" 
                          messageProtectionOrder ="EncryptBeforeSign"
                          requireDerivedKeys="false" 
                          enableUnsecuredResponse="true" 
                          allowInsecureTransport="true" 
                          securityHeaderLayout="Lax" >
                </security>
                <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Negotiate"  
                               transferMode="Buffered" 
                               maxReceivedMessageSize="67819876"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
        <wsFederationHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsFederationHttpBinding_ESLGetStoreConfigurationBinding" >
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message negotiateServiceCredential="true" 
                             establishSecurityContext="false"
                             algorithmSuite="Basic128" >
                        <issuer address="http://192.168.100.25" 
                                bindingConfiguration="UsernameBinding"
                                binding="customBinding">
                            <identity>
                                <dns value="WIN-7TN6ALB4TVK.oag-dev.sei"/>
                            </identity>
                        </issuer>
                    </message>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsFederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Identification"/>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="false" userName="oag-server" password="Password!"/>
</system.web>
```

Providing Network Credentials was also done in code; but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is if you can get a sample working request/response pair (or multiple messages in case of spnego) generated by one stack (e.g. client and server are java). Then it will be a game of tuning WCF to one of these messages. Currently there is too much unknown. Also AFAIK SPNEGO is a WCF only supported protocol (=windows credential negotiation at SOAP message level) so may be the server uses something else.

The specific error you got may imply that the server uses SOAP11 while you send SOAP12 (e.g. you may need basic http binding). But any config change must be done in the context of knowing more about which SOAP the server allows.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and concise response. I'll check with Oracle and find out exactly what version of SOAP they're using and in fact point them to this post for further reflection.